# Do I need to bind event handlers to `this` with TypeScript + React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component with a simple button handler method. If I don't bind the `onClick` handler to `this` in the constructor (or inline on the `onClick` itself), then I get an error because the context of the `handleAdd` method is not the instance where my component's state is...

I understand how the `bind` works, but is there a workaround to avoid having to use `bind` all over the place with TypeScript + React?

```
export class TodoList extends React.Component<ITodoListProps, Partial<ITodoListState>> {
    constructor(props: ITodoListProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { items: props.items };

        this.handleAdd.bind(this);
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add</button>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.items.map((todo, i) => {
                        return <TodoItem key={i} name={todo.name} />
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleAdd(e: any) {
        this.setState({
            items: [...this.state.items, { name: "foo" }]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is someone downvoting these? Leave a comment so we can improve the quality please.

Comment: Just like YouTube - there's always a downvote - no matter what.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> but is there a workaround to avoid having to use bind all over the place with TypeScript + React?

Yes. Use an arrow function:

```
handleAdd = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({
        items: [...this.state.items, { name: "foo" }]
    });
}
```

## More

- [A quick video](https://egghead.io/lessons/typescript-create-stateful-react-components-using-typescript)
- [More docs on arrow](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function works for anonym functions but reduces the extensibility of the class (if you want to extend that class and redefine the function but using super).

To call the function being a member of the class the easy way is use bind.

Is worst use bind than use anonym functions?